# UWP Background Task Error

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, background-task

I want create a Background task which starts when the application starts. For that I use Application Trigger.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    var trigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
    BackgroundManagement.RegisterBackgroundTask("InternetBackgroundTask.InternetBackground", "Internet", trigger, null);
    await trigger.RequestAsync();
```

**BackgroundManagement.cs**

```
    public static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint,string taskName,IBackgroundTrigger trigger,IBackgroundCondition condition)
    {
        //
        // Check for existing registrations of this background task.
        //

        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {

            if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
            {
                //
                // The task is already registered.
                //

                return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
            }
        }

        //
        // Register the background task.
        //

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = taskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
        builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        

        if (condition != null)
        {

            builder.AddCondition(condition);
        }

        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
       
        return task;
    }
```

**Mytask on another project**

```
namespace InternetBackgroundTask
{
public sealed class InternetBackground : IBackgroundTask
{

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Run Background Task");
    }
}
```

So when I launch my application I have this error :

> Exception thrown at 0x776BE26B (KernelBase.dll) in backgroundTaskHost.exe: 0x04242420 (parameters: 0x31415927, 0x5DE30000, 0x003CED68).
>
> Exception thrown at 0x776BE26B in backgroundTaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EETypeLoadException at memory location 0x003CDF18.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x776BE26B in backgroundTaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x776BE26B in backgroundTaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EETypeLoadException at memory location 0x003CDF18.

I've referenced my background Task in my project and I've added my background Task in my manifest

Comment: Have you referenced your windows runtime component containing your background task in your other project?

Comment: Yes it's referenced.

Comment: Do you have the option to change the os language to english? My french is too bad to translate it to the english equivalent words. The error message sounds a bit familiar to me I think. 
Have you also tried unregistering the task before returning / creating it new?

Comment: I change error message french to english. Yes I tried to unregistering, I even uninstall and install my application.

Comment: Please send it to me in english.

Comment: I directly modify my post

Comment: thank you, but its not the exception I tought it was. At what point does the app crash?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wich are not obvious from your snipped:

Have you declared your background task under "Declarations" in your Package.appxmanifest?

And second:
In what project type is "InternetBackground.cs"? It should be a Windows Runtime Component

Comment: First question is yes I think, it's in his last sentence below code.